# Cannot run MongoDB aggregate command (OperationFailure)

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I am trying to use a MongoDB aggregation pipeline command in python (using PyMongo), but I am running into this error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: {aggregate: 1} is not valid for '$match'; a collection is required., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': "{aggregate: 1} is not valid for '$match'; a collection is required.", 'code': 73, 'codeName': 'InvalidNamespace'}
```

I tried removing the first match but it will just change '$match' to '$project'. This is the pipeline I am using:

```
    [
        {
            "$match": {"$text": {"$search": "{self.keyword}"}}
        },
        {
            "$project":
            {
                "wholeDate": {"$dateFromString": {"dateString": "$date"}},
                "year": {"$year": {"$dateFromString": {"dateString": "$date"}}},
            }
        },
        {
            "$match": {"wholeDate": {"$gte": "{self.date_from_}", "$lte": "{self.date_until_}"}}
        },
        {
            "$group":
            {
                "_id": {"year": "$year"},
                "count": {"$sum": 1}
            }
        }
    ]
```

When I run the same pipeline directly on MongoDB it works fine. When working it should give this output:

```
{ "_id" : { "year" : 2018 }, "count" : 34 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't think I'd need to specify the collection again by giving an argument when running the aggregate function on a specified database. I found on here (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#command-fields) that there is a collection argument so I changed my function call to:

```
mongo.test.aggregate(aggregate="test", pipeline=self.pipeline)
```

and it now works fine. Some docs never mentioned the collection argument.